# gravity inside html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to do a copy of the original super mario game using html5 canvas just for fun and to learn more about the canvas tool and it's animation but i am stuck at making Mario do it's jump here is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2tLCk/1/

how should i fix my `up` function to make mario jump and return back to the ground like in this website `http://blog.nihilogic.dk/` i tried to understand it's code but i couldn't ?

```
if (keydown.up) {

            vy += gravity;
            character.CurentPos = 11;
            character.x += character.speed;
            character.y += vy;

        }
```

Comment: You should dynamically calculate max height of jump and then check `if (character.y >= maxHeight) { setTimeout(function() { character.y -= someValue }, gravity); }` something like this ;)

Comment: could u post a jsfiddle please

Comment: I'm not sure that is best approach, but it's should work something like this. [jsFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/2tLCk/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a jumping Mario http://jsfiddle.net/2tLCk/22/.

If *jumping* is 1 - going up. If *jumping* is 2 - going down.

```
if(jumping){
     if(jumping == 1) {
          if(character.y > 140) character.y -= gravity;
          else jumping = 2;
     } else if(jumping == 2) {
          if(character.y < 184) character.y += gravity;
          else{
               character.y = 184;
               jumping = false;
               character.CurentPos = 6;
          }
     }
}else if(keydown.up) {
    jumping = 1;
    character.CurentPos = 11;
}
```

And you would probably want to use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval().

Answer (score 1):

You basically want the gravitiy to be always active, not only when pushing the down key.
When jumping (key up) you have to add to vy. Like this:

```
    if(keydown.up) {
         vy += -2;   
    }
    vy += gravity;
    if(character.y > 184) { // simple collision detection for ground floor
        vy = 0;
        character.y = 184;
    }
    //character.CurentPos = 11;
    //character.x += character.speed;
    character.y += vy;
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/pjQb3/

Comment: It is because of the collision detection with the ground floor (at "if(character.y > 184)"). Y-Position is greater than 184 at one frame and is reset to 184 at the next frame. You need a better collision detection algorithm. Mine is very simple and only takes the floor into account. It just prevents mario to fall out of the screen.

Comment: @Sora your link in your comment redirects instantly to advertising pages.

Comment: yeah but can u see the background ? it's super mario game where u can make mario move and jump i want to implement the exact jumping effect in my code .How can i update my code to get this jumping effect ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
// Global forces
character.vy += gravity;

// User input
if (keydown.up) {
  character.vy += -2;
}

// Final location
if (character.y + character.vy >= 184) {
  // Update player location.
  character.y += character.vy;
} else {
  // Player was about to move past ground so place player directly on ground
  // and reset velocity.
  character.y = 184;
  character.vy = 0;
}
```