# html 5 gravity attempt inside canvas when hitting the up arrow button

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2ueWL/4/

What I am trying to do basically is making a gravity effect. My goal here is to let the gravity work even when the ball is on the block; as you can see when the ball is on the block, the gravity doesn't work anymore and I can't find the bug in my code.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
if (ball.jumping) {
    if (ball.falling) {
        if (ball.y > ball.MaxJump) {
            ball.y -= gravity;
        }
        else {
            ball.falling = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ((ball.y < ch - ball.radius)) {
            ball.y += gravity;
            if ((ball.y < Blocks.collection[0].blockY - ball.radius)) {

                ball.y = Blocks.collection[0].blockY - ball.radius;

                if (ball.OnBlock && ball.jumping && !ball.falling) {
                    ball.MaxJump = ball.y - 100;
                }
                else{
                    ball.falling = true;
                    ball.jumping = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (!ball.OnBlock && ball.falling)
                ball.y = ch - ball.radius;
            ball.jumping = false;
        }
    }

} else if ((keydown.up && !ball.jumping) || (keydown.up && ball.OnBlock)) {
    ball.color = "#4285F4";

    ball.jumping = true;
    ball.falling = true;
}
```

Could you please tell me what I am missing and how I can fix it?

Comment: Just saw your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204001/gravity-inside-html5-canvas?rq=1 you missed out the answer of @DrHund with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pjQb3/ with the right answer about gravity

Answer (score 0):

1. You should check the X parameter of the ball as well to see if its over the block.
2. To simulate gravity you should constantly extract the factor from the speed not the altitude.

Comment: what do you mean from the speed ?

Comment: I mean the amount of distance the ball moves upward in a given period of time.

Comment: you mean the gravity value ?

Comment: see my comment on your question above

Comment: i updated my question please check